# Dot until page numbers in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to make a table of content with the dot line from text to the page number.

I used this

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{\widthof{0}}
```

It works fine until the page number is larger than 100.

The problem looks like this

[image]

So when I change the width to

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{\widthof{00}}
```

The problem is the dotted line is not there until the page number

[image]

How to solve these problem?

Comment: You might want to include the package \cftsetpnumwidth comes from in the tags, and full MWE would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The first key is to use `\addtocontents` to change `\@pnumwidth` in the middle of the TOC.  (This will need some more work to handle the `\listoffigures`, etc.)

The second was to use \AddToHook{shipout/after}` to automatically make the change on page 99.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\sbox0{\normalsize\normalfont 22}%
\edef\@pnumwidth{\the\wd0}
\sbox0{\normalsize\normalfont 222}%
\edef\@pnumplus{\the\wd0}

\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\ifnum\value{page}=99\relax
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\@pnumwidth\string\@pnumplus}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{99}
\chapter{Not Zero}
\section{Yadda Yadda}
\newpage

\section{OMG It worked!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice answer regarding adjusting the length of the dotted line, which I have approved. However, as I read it the OP wanted the end of the dotted line to abut the page number (no space between them). I tried but couldn't do that. Perhaps the OP should rethink the request, which would look bad if it were possible to have no space.

Comment: @PeterWilson - Eek!  One could adjust the dot spacing, but that gives a whole extra level of complexity.

Comment: Complexity, yes! If the OP  was really picky that would involve setting the dot spacing for every individual entry in the ToC. I'm greatly inclined to let the OP try and achieve the pickiness which I'm pretty sure no reader will notice.

Answer (score 0):

Not a regular answer but too long for a comment.

In the normal classes (`book` etc) there is a space between the end of the dotted line and the page number, irrespective of the length of the page number. Also the page numbers are set, at the right, of a box of a fixed width. This means that there will be a space between the end of the dottedline and the page number. This space will be smaller for longer page numbers.

The normal result would be as you showed in your second graphic, not what you showed in your first graphic.

Why do you think that the dotted line should continue right up to the page number?

Perhaps you could use the `tocloft` package's `\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign{l}` to have all page numbers aligned left so that there would be a constant space between the end of the dotted line and the page numbers.

It would be very helpful if you provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed what you had done and what the problem was.